# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\templates'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook

I am trying a create a simple flask app using Jupyter Notebook.
The Tutorial I am following is suggesting me to create a directory - **templates** and put the html file inside it.
When I tried to create the directory, it is showing " **File already exists: templates** ".
But I am unable to find this directory and when I tried to access it programmatically, it is showing -

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Username\templates'

Answer (score -1):

This may be a permissions problem.

Running the app as administrator may solve it.